# Add Date parameter and time parameter to single date time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm modifying a store procedure in SQL Server 2008.  The original procedure took in two dates

```
@StartDate DATETIME
@EndDate   DATETIME
```

And would convert the time portion to the Earliest and latest possible times respectively.

I have added two additional parameters to accept Time Portions.

```
@StartTime DATETIME
@EndTime   DATETIME
```

The Time portions are optional.

An RDL report file generates the report online for the users.  The logic needs to occur in the Stored Proc.

What I have so far is not much, as I'm a C# programmer leaving my element.

```
IF (@StartTime IS NULL)
    SET @StartDate = fn_SetBeginningTime(@StartDate) -- Sets time portion to earliest value 
ELSE
    -- This is where I don't know how to add the time from @StartTime to the time portion of the datetime value @StartDate
IF (@EndTime IS NULL)
    -- This will do the same as the start time/start date
```

Comment: If you're on 2008, why aren't you using more appropriate datatypes for these parameters (e.g. `date` and `time`). They'd make the answer easier to write without requiring extra assumptions

Comment: As stated, I'm a C# programmer, this is my first foray into SQL coding.  My guess, is DATETIME is used for @StartDate/@EndDate since a time portion is being added to them and the fields they represent are DateTime fields.

Comment: Take a step back and tell us what you're doing with the time portion of the date. In SQL Server, the time portion of datetime defaults to midnight if you do not specify the time. E.G. `Set @StarDate = '5/9/2011'` means the time portion of the variable would be midnight.

Comment: in TSQL the `datetime` datatype stores a date and a time.  Some people simulate a date only by setting the time portion to `00:00:00.000` but the time is still always there.  SO, actually your original procedure already takes two date+time parameters.

Comment: Just for clarification, I thought it prudent to fill in information in case others come looking and find this post.  The original stored proc used two date time parameters, @StartDate, @StartEnd.  There are functions in place to to put the time values of those DateTimes in at 00:00:01 and 23:59:59 respectively to include all records that fell equal to or in between those dates.  I'm responsible for adding Time filters so that users may or may not select a specific time frame to search for.  Hence the use if IF statements to check if Time values were added by the user or not.

Comment: **you shouls NEVER use `00:00:01` and `23:59:59`**, you are will eventually find you miss data! datetime values exists with fraction of seconds like `00:00:00.020`! you need to use just `00:00:00`. If you have date time values: `@start datetime='1/1/2011'` which will actually be `01/01/2011 00:00:00.000` and `@end datetime='12/13/2011'` which will be stored as `12/31/2011 00:00:00.000` you form your query like: `WHERE column>=@start and column<@end+1` that will get every row for year 2011 and not miss `1/1/2011 00:00:00.080` or `12/13/2011 23:59:59.857` like your logic will.

Comment: the `+1` just increments @end by one day.  so your essentiall have this where clause: `WHERE column>='1/1/2011 00:00:00.00' and column<'1/1/2012 00:00:00.00'`.  anything short of that will miss data.  I seen people use logic like you are doing using `23:59:59` and it missed data, big pain.  lesson just learn to do it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

1. By earliest you mean 00:00:00 on the start date
2. By latest you mean 00:00:00 on the day after enddate (for use with `<=`)

Should there be any, this will ignore the time from a `@*Date` param and the date from a`@*Time` param.

```
declare @StartDate DATETIME = '15 jul 2010'
declare @EndDate   DATETIME = '15 jul 2010'
declare @StartTime DATETIME = '06:06:06'
declare @EndTime   DATETIME = null

--always make @StartDate/@EndDate's time 00:00:00
SET @StartDate = CAST(@StartDate AS DATE)
SET @EndDate =   CAST(@EndDate AS DATE)

IF (@StartTime IS NOT NULL)                -- set @StartDate's time to @StartTime
    SET @StartDate += CAST(@StartTime AS TIME)

IF (@EndTime IS NULL)
    SET @EndDate += 1                      --set it to midnight
ELSE
    SET @EndDate += CAST(@EndTime AS TIME) --set @EndDate's time to @EndTime

select @StartDate, @EndDate

>>> 2010-07-15 06:06:06.000,2010-07-16 00:00:00.000
```

For DATE / TIME;

```
declare @StartDate DATE = '15 jul 2010'
declare @EndDate   DATE = '15 jul 2010'
declare @StartTime TIME = null
declare @EndTime   TIME = '22:22:22'

declare @start datetime = cast(@StartDate as datetime) + coalesce(@StartTime, cast('00:00:00' as time))
declare @end   datetime = cast(@EndDate   as datetime) + coalesce(@EndTime,   cast('23:59:59' as time))

select @start, @end
```

Comment: Your assumptions are on target.  The Functions fn_SetTimes, will set a start time Midnight, and end time to 23:59:59 for use with <=.

Comment: I guess this leads me another question.  Since I can change the parameter type of @StartTime and @EndTime.  Would it be better to declare them as TIME values?  This way, IF (@StartTime IS NOT NULL) SET @StartDate += @StartTime or would the CAST be necessary either way since we're adding a TIME portion to a DATETIME value?

Comment: Part of my real dilemma is there is no test environment.  So any changes I make are going onto a production server live.  Stupid, I know, but I don't make the rules here.

Comment: Yes, I did create a new copy of the stored proc and am using that to make my changes, not just modifying the existing.

Comment: You could use DATE/TIME params, but you would need 2 new variables to store the final DATE+TIME, and you would also need to use DATEADD() as DATE + int isn't valid as it is with a date time